# Why is my if statement not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I did a simple experiment to make sure I know what is going on as I'm new to programming. This has me stumped and I'm getting angry with my computer for lying to me. :)

Here is my vb.net

```
If table2.Rows.Count = 0 Then
    LBLCannary.Visible = True
End If
```

Now if I hover over during debug it tells me the count is zero. ie table2.Rows.Count 0 but for some odd reason it never goes to the next line in the `if`. if the table is empty. Why won't it work?

Answer: Silly newbie mistake, All this is done after return and nothing happens after a function returns something.

Comment: Maybe it's a NullReferenceException, which you may not throw while debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the reverse?

```
If table2 IsNot Nothing AndAlso table2.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    'do nothing
Else
    'if no rows or if table is empty
    LBLCannary.Visible = True
End If
```

or widen your condition to

```
If table2 Is Nothing OrElse table2.Rows.Count < 1 Then

    LBLCannary.Visible = True
End If
```

Comment: Yes the Reverse works and gives the desired effect the former still wont work

Comment: Can you try widening your condition as suggested?

Comment: Im sorry I found the Answer it was my own silly new guy mistake. I did all this after the return so none of it was actually happening.